# pass string as bool from C# to PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, boolean

i've created a c# windows form that running multiple PowerShell commands, and I have issue with one if the command
PowerShell command:

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity "email" -AddAdditionalResponse:$true -AdditionalResponse:"message"
```

How I run it from C#:

```
myCommand = new Command("Set-CalendarProcessing");
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("identity", desiredRoom);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("AddAdditionalResponse", "true");
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("AdditionalResponse", message);
            plPileLine = rsRemoteRunspace.CreatePipeline();
            plPileLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);
            RsResultsresults = plPileLine.Invoke();
```

I'm getting error that 'true' passed as a string and powershell isn't converting to bool, I tried '$True', '1', none of them worked, please advice.
thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to pass it as plain `bool` without quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `true` is a keyword in C#. It seems obvious, but it's worth asking if you tried:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("AddAdditionalResponse", true);
```